# Programatically Send Notification Email for an Office 365 Hosted Email Using REST or Python

Tags: python, email, azure, active-directory, office365

I am starting work on a project that will involve sending an auto generated email to a user. I am (most likely) going to build the application using Python and Django and host it as an Azure web app. The outgoing email address (hello@example.com) is hosted on Office 365. After some digging it looks like the recommended method of sending emails is the [365 Outlook API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/api/use-outlook-rest-api#DefineOutlookRESTAPI). All the documentation shows how to authenticate using AAD for a user that is logging in. However, I need to access the same email address regardless of who is using the web app.

Is there a way to securely get access to an AAD token on the backed of the server without storing a password in plaintext? Preferably the it would be in Python or REST but if need be I can switch technologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an app only following [Client Credentials Grant flow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn645543.aspx), leveraging which you can authenticate and authorize for AAD in backend.

Here is a code sample on GitHub https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-python-graphapi-oauth2-0-access, which builds an app-only app leveraging AAD in Django.

Any further concern, please feel free to let me know.